# How to count the lines and how to extract numbers from lines and then compute the average of the numbers

Tags: python

Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0.0
average = 0.0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    fline = float(line.split("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")[1])
    average = fline
    print("Average spam confidence:", average)
```

Now, its not giving me the average.

What its posting is this.

> Average spam confidence: 0.8475 ← Mismatch
> Average spam confidence: 0.6178
> Average spam confidence: 0.6961000000000001
> Average spam confidence: 0.7565
> Average spam confidence: 0.7625999999999999
> Average spam confidence: 0.7556
> Average spam confidence: 0.7002
> Average spam confidence: 0.7615
> Average spam confidence: 0.7601
> Average spam confidence: 0.7605
> Average spam confidence: 0.6959
> Average spam confidence: 0.7606000000000001
> Average spam confidence: 0.7559
> Average spam confidence: 0.7605
> Average spam confidence: 0.6932
> Average spam confidence: 0.7558
> Average spam confidence: 0.6526
> Average spam confidence: 0.6948
> Average spam confidence: 0.6528
> Average spam confidence: 0.7002
> Average spam confidence: 0.7554
> Average spam confidence: 0.6956
> Average spam confidence: 0.6959
> Average spam confidence: 0.7556
> Average spam confidence: 0.9846
> Average spam confidence: 0.8509
> Average spam confidence: 0.9907

Comment: What is the format of the file? What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

Lines which start with a non-numeric string will *definitely* not happily become a `float`

Instead, you could `.split()` the lines

For example if your line is `X-DSPAM-Confidence: 1.0`

You could split on `:`

```py
>>> "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 1.0".split(": ")
['X-DSPAM-Confidence', '1.0']
>>> float("X-DSPAM-Confidence: 1.0".split(": ")[1])
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you just need to split the line before converting it to float :

```
fname = "highscore.txt"
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    print(line)
    fline = float(line.split("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")[1])
print("Done")
```